# Have installed tensorflow, but still get "no module named tensorflow" message

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the information about environment:

[image: python-env-and-packages]

The error message:

[image: error-message]

Comment: try shifiting the script in the same drive and then again try

Comment: @Ava,Did you tried as suggested above? Did you tested it on command prompt by
activating env?

Comment: The first image is not related to the second image since the first image looks like it is part of an IDE. Instead, please run `pip list` or `conda list` to see what is installed in `venv3`.